# How to implement a blocking queue in C++ to process data between threads?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to make an app that will have two threads.
One will produce data (file paths and an action to be performed for that path - create/update/delete) and the other thread will need to consume this data and actually perform the tasks.

For this I thought to have a queue and from one thread to put data in it and from the other to take the items and performa the actions sequentially.

My problem is how do I make this data to be shareable between these threads and then how can I make the second thread to block while waiting for data to be put in the queue? Just having a while to check if queue is not empty would eat CPU like crazy for nothing. Adding a "sleep" to check every few milliseconds or seconds would not be efficient.

How can this be done? Any libraries that implement such data?

Comment: You can use `std::mutex` or, if you are implementing queue code, use std::atomic. I share you a code where tow thread are sinchronized, my be it could help you understand how to us mutexs.

Comment: Example C code for Windows that copies a file using one thread to read data and another to write data, using a custom queue based on single linked list. Note this makes use of Windows WaitForMultipleObjects() to wait for a mutex and a semaphore with a single atomic call.  [mtcopy.zip](http://rcgldr.net/misc/mtcopy.zip) .

Comment: Apache's apr_queue implementation is time-honored. Here's a stripped down version built on pthreads: https://github.com/chrismerck/rpa_queue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of examples for you:

- [Intel TBB concurrent_bounded_queue](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506201).
- [EventQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711414/what-is-the-proper-way-of-doing-event-handling-in-c/9711916#9711916) with usage example.
- [Detailed design explanation](https://juanchopanzacpp.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/concurrent-queue-c11/) of building a concurrent queue.
- [Another concurrent queue](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue), along with benchmark comparisons against TBB and Boost.

Comment: The last one seems really promising.