# ThreadSafe Queue c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

I am trying to make a thread safe queue in c++ with the help of `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`.The Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<queue>
#include<atomic>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class SafeQueue{
public:
    queue<T>qu;
    mutex mut;
    condition_variable cv;
    SafeQueue(){}
    SafeQueue(queue<T>q):qu(q){}
    void push(int val){
        unique_lock<mutex>uq(mut);
        cv.wait(uq,[&](){return qu.empty();});
        qu.push(val);
        uq.unlock();
    }
    bool isEmpty(){
//      unique_lock<mutex>uq(mut);
//      uq.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();
        return qu.empty();
    }
};
void inc(SafeQueue<int>& sq){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        continue;
    if(sq.isEmpty())
        sq.push(1);
}
void inc1(SafeQueue<int>& sq){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        continue;
    if(sq.isEmpty())
        sq.push(2);
}

int main(){
    queue<int>qu;
    SafeQueue<int> sq(qu);
    thread t1(inc,ref(sq));
    thread t2(inc1,ref(sq));
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    cout<<sq.qu.front();
}
```

A thread Safe queue is supposed to output `1` at the end,but the output is random either `1` or `2` that means it is not thread safe.Why is this particular program not working?

Comment: Working example for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669316/412080

Comment: Check my tlock: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1186797/tlock-Any-Cplusplus-object-read-write-thread-safe

Comment: thank you for the suggestions but I want to learn what is wrong with my piece of code..If any please suggest me

Comment: @AbhinavSingh I've already told you. Nothing. It's working. The only thing wrong is your expectation of what should happen....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It *doesn't* mean the program isn't thread safe. It doesn't mean it's ill-defined and can crash.

It just means your program's logic is not written to add the items to the queue in any particular order.

If you want those two items to be added in a specific order, push both from *one* thread.

Thread safety doesn't mean your application runs as if it only had one thread.

**Your program is working fine.**

Comment: But my actual answer should be 1 beacuse i m pushing it first and then afters function `inc1()` will run,this is what I m trying to achieve more like a concurrent process.If I m wrong could you provide me with a valid logic for this to achieve.And one more thing when I use same function in both thread it just hangs in runtime(waiting for a thread to be finished) but I dont think any deadlock situation is being created in this case.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh In what sense are you "pushing it first"? The two threads run _concurrently_ ("at the same time"). That's the whole point of threads. If you do not want concurrency, do not use concurrency.

Comment: Could you please make me clear what a thread safe queue is (I m new to multiprogramming)is it what I want?Sorry for this weird question though?

Comment: @AbhinavSingh I have no idea what you want. You should review your book on multi-threaded programming.

Comment: Suppose I want my queue to have two elements and I want in order `1` then `2`.So I am making two threads to make the operation fast,but in doing so I loose the order of my data..what should I do to correct it?

Comment: @AbhinavSingh You can't just throw threads at a problem to "make it fast". That's not how it works. Your program will be fastest, and satisfy your needs, if you literally just ask it to "push 1", then ask it to "push 2". In order, in sequence. That's it. Making the two things happen "at the same time" doesn't accomplish _anything_ except remove that ordering constraint. This is not what threads are for. You use threads when you have several [mostly] unrelated operations that might as well happen in parallel to save time, either because one or the other _blocks_, or to use multiple CPUs.

Comment: okay I m getting it now..Thank you for the answer @LightnessRaces

Comment: @AbhinavSingh No problemo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205953/discussion-between-abhinav-singh-and-lightness-races-by-sa-3-0).

Comment: I think that's enough now :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspects where your code is flawed:

- Whenever you access a shared structure, that must be guarded by a mutex. You have a mutex, but you don't use it in `isEmpty()`. Document that connection, this is important no not lose track. Also, do the same for the CV, document when it's being signaled.
- Concerning `isEmpty()`, that function is useless anyway. Even if the queue was not empty at one point in time, there is nothing that prevents it from becoming empty the next second.
- Re-read the documentation for `unique_lock`. Your way of using it is more complicated than necessary.
- The use of the CV is also odd: Normally, you use it to notify waiters of a change. You signal it unconditionally in a function that only seems to query some state.

Comment: I m using mutex lock in isEmpty with (the comment code in function i`sEmpty()`) but it was not working and producing the same result so I uncommented it to see if it gives me correct output.About `unique_lock` I think it is used as I have written above in my program.

Comment: Well, then your question posted here is bad: I can only comment on the code you provide, not on code you have somewhere else or tried before. Be clear!