# C++ event like driven example

Tags: c++

Back story, I have mostly written in C#.  Now I want to practice my C++.

I keep seeing myself comparing what c# can do and trying to search for it on c++.  The question is are there event like driven handlers in c++ that can get me similar on how c# is done?  I'm not looking for the exact same thing.  I'm just asking from a confused c# point of view.

Also I am trying my hardest not to use any outside libraries like Boost or ACE.

Comment: While this does not make this a bad question, you are approaching programming in C++ from a bad direction. Do not try to program in C++ as you would in C#. Program C++ according to C++ idioms and best practices. Celebrate what C++ and C# have in common, but when they differ take advantage of what C++ offers and you will write better C++ code.

Comment: How about libevent https://libevent.org/ ? I know you said nothing outside Boost or Ace, but when developing applications in C++ you will likely need libraries. In addition, if you're interested in learning other languages as well check out how it's done in golang (with channels) https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2 .

Comment: @Tomer I will look at it.  The reason I trying to avoid those libraries is the company i'm looking at doesn't use it.  I am also trying to challenge myself to figure out how to do things without feeling that I'm taking the shortcut.

Comment: Have you read this comment before? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9711414#comment47767325_9711916

Comment: @sin my recommendation as a software engineer, is to always take shortcuts when possible (and when it makes sense). Always assume other developers have already thought about "problems" and found ways to solve them. Sometimes these developers are nice enough to share their solutions with the world (e.g. open source libraries).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing in C++ core language or standard library that is like C# events.

Comment: This is true, but it's not particularly hard to write an event loop with C++'s built in (as of C++11) threading. After that it's just a matter of how you intend to handle the callbacks.